# filter dataframe and using previous row data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df, shown below.

```
   date         price   roll
   2020-01-01   103     False
   2020-01-02   105     False
   2020-01-03   104     True 
   2020-01-04   101     False
   ...
   2020-02-01   97      False
   2020-02-02   98      True
   2020-02-03   101     False
```

When roll is true I need to perform a calculation but using the previous price.

So I know I can filter my dataframe with the line like below however I need to use the price on the previous row. Is there anyway to do this without me looping through my dataframe? Or is best to just add another column to my dataframe which is the price column lagged by one obsveration?

> df.query('roll==True')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method to move column up or down:

```
df['previous_price'] = df.price.shift(1)
```

And then you can use this shifted column in your queries.